# OpenGL: Only some textures work

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am using the RayWenderlich OpenGL tutorial found [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4404/opengl-es-2-0-for-iphone-tutorial-part-2-textures) as a starting point for an app.
Upon adding my own textures though, I ran into some difficulty. No matter what any image I add to the project will just come up black. I've tried different settings of png's (which are used in the sample) and JPEG's. I've tried just changing the file name that is loaded and drawn by default and making a different texture instance and both just come up black.

I tried opening the floor texture in Photoshop and just resaving it, and it just came up invisible in the game.

But I tried duplicating the projects original tile_floor.png file with a different name which worked perfectly, so I'm assuming opengl requires a very specific format.

What do I have to do to get this working?

EDIT:

This is the method used to load the images:

```
static GLuint setupTexture(NSString *fileName) {

// 1
CGImageRef spriteImage = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName].CGImage;
if (!spriteImage) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load image %@", fileName);
    exit(1);
}

// 2
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(spriteImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(spriteImage);

GLubyte * spriteData = (GLubyte *) calloc(width*height*4, sizeof(GLubyte));

CGContextRef spriteContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(spriteData, width, height, 8, width*4, CGImageGetColorSpace(spriteImage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);    

// 3
CGContextDrawImage(spriteContext, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), spriteImage);

CGContextRelease(spriteContext);

// 4
GLuint texName;
glGenTextures(1, &texName);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texName);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST); 

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, spriteData);

free(spriteData);        
return texName;

}
```

Comment: I've often encountered difficulties getting the OpenGL settings just right. It sounds like that's the issue. Why don't you show us some relevant code and we might be able to help?

Comment: There really isn't much relevant code, just what is in the sample. It comes with a method that you put a file name in and it returns the GLuint associated with the texture. I just change the input string to my my texture. I'll put the code in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-power-of-two textures you need to set parameter GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE for texture before glTexImage2D.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE)
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that my problem is that the dimensions of my images weren't a power of two
(2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024). Apparently OpenGL ES requires this.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer (only if it's the correct solution to your problem, of course).